# Model ${\sf ZF}$ that "spreads" members of ${\cal P}(X)$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

Is there a model of ${\sf ZF}$ such that there is an infinite set $X$ and a injective map $f:{\cal P}(X)\to {\cal P}(X)$ so that for $a\neq b \in {\cal P}(X)$ we have $|f(a)\cap f(b)| \leq 1$?

---

**Note.** As user Gro-Tsen in the comments below points out, if we weaken the condition $|f(a)\cap f(b)| \leq 1$ to "$f(a)\cap f(b)$ is finite", then the resulting statement is a theorem of ${\sf ZFC}$.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that (it is an easy theorem of ZF that) there exists $f\colon\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $f(a)\cap f(b)$ is *finite* for every $a\neq b$ in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (see, e.g., Jech, *Set Theory*, third millennium ed., lemma 9.21).

Comment: (In fact, the proof of the statement in my previous comment is so easy I might as well write it here: map an infinite binary sequence to the sequence of its finite prefixes, and use obvious bijections to get a map $f\colon\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with the same properties.)

Comment: Thanks @Gro-Tsen - I am aware of this result; if you strengthen the finiteness condition you mention to "$f(a)\cap f(b)$ is empty or at most a singleton" (or contains at most $n$ elements for some fixed $n\in\mathbb{N})$ then the resulting statement is false in ZFC, but maybe not in ZF. But coming back to your statement, I will include it in the problem statement -- thank you again!

Comment: Where can I find a proof of the fact that the statement with $|f(a)\cap f(b)|\leq 1$ is refutable in ZFC?  How about with $|f(a)\cap f(b)|\leq k$ (with $k$ constant)?  (Maybe these questions are stupid.)

Comment: What @Gro-Tsen says is true. If you weaken this to a finite intersection then $\Bbb N$ produces an example without needing choice. You don't need choice to produce a continuum sized almost-disjoint family of subsets of $\Bbb N$ (and before you post this as a question, this was asked on MSE a few times, and probably here also, like in the second comment by Gro-Tsen).

Comment: I'm also curious how to prove in ZFC there there is no infinite $X$ and injective $f\colon \mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $|f(a)\cap f(b)|\leq k$ for all $a\neq b$, even for $k=1$.

Comment: Alex: Choose for each $a$ with $|f(a)|>k$, a $k+1$-element subset of $f(a)$. Under the axiom of choice, $|X|^{k+1}=|X|$, so there are at most $|X|$ such elements of $P(X)$. Similarly, the number of those elements of $P(X)$ for which $|f(a)|\leq k$ is also $\leq|X|$, so we get that $|P(X)|\leq|X|$, contradicting Cantor's theorem.

Comment: Ah, so it is easy. Thanks, Péter. I'll also alert @Gro-Tsen who asked the question as well.

Answer (score -1):

What if we make an attempt like this as follows: There is no such ZF model. We can prove in ZF that there is no infinite set X and injective function $f:\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\vert f(a)\cap f(b)\vert\leq 1$ for all $a\neq b\in \mathcal{P}(X)$.
There are atmost $\vert X \vert^{2}$ many elements $a$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\vert f(a)\vert > 1$. Similarly, there are atmost $\vert X \vert^{2}$ many elements $a$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\vert f(a)\vert \leq 1$. Hence, we obtain $\vert\mathcal{P}(X)\vert\leq\vert X \vert ^{2}$. Now it's possible to prove in ZF that $\vert\mathcal{P}(X)\vert\ \not\leq \vert X \vert ^{2}$ for any infinite set X and thus we obtain a contradiction.

Comment: "There are atmost $\vert X \vert^{2}$ many elements $a$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\vert f(a)\vert > 1$." How do you prove this in ZF?

Comment: You cannot prove in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $|\mathcal P (X)|>|X|^2 $ for $X$ infinite.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo What if we use the Theorem 4.2 from the Combinatorial Set Theory book by Lorenz J. Halbeisen ? I think then we can claim in ZF that $\vert\mathcal{P}(X)\vert \not\leq \vert X \vert^{2}$ for any infinite set X. I edited.

Comment: But you seem to assume that $|\mathcal P(X)|$ and $|X|^2$ are comparable. Why are they comparable?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, we can't say they are comparable in ZF. I didn't assume $\vert \mathcal{P}(X)\vert$ and $\vert X \vert^{2}$ are comparable. I was trying to obtain $\vert \mathcal{P}(X)\vert \leq \vert X \vert^{2}$, which is not possible since there is no injection from $\mathcal{P}(X)$ to $X^{2}$.